# fullpage.js enable scroll inside div without scroll page when autoscrolling false

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, fullpage.js

Hay,
I'm using jquery.fullpage.min.js plugin in my site for fullpage and scrolloverflow.min.js for scroll inside divs. I set `autoScrolling:false, scrollOverflow:true` because i I don't want auto scrolling, and I want overflow scroll inside div.

The problem is that when I scroll the overflowed div, the whole page scrolled too.
I tried use `normalScrollElements:"my-div"`, but it works only when `autoScrolling:true`.
how can I avoid page scroll when user scroll the overflowed div?

Thank for help!

Answer (score 0):

Few things:

- autoScrolling:false, scrollOverflow:true are not compatible options. You can probably see an error message saying exactly this in your JS console. So expect problems in different browsers :)
- normalScrollElements won't have any effect when using autoScrolling:false.
- normalScrollElements won't have any effect inside scrollOverflow